# How to use doctrine migration without console

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

how can I use Doctrine Migrations on the shared web hosting where is no access to SSH? I tried looking everywhere for same solution but I didn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Use it locally, then copy and paste the commands in your PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Use @A.L.'s suggestion, although you could run the resulting SQL from a controller instead of using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: As I thought that I need access to SSH. Ok thanks for your time. :)